# Custom IAM policy for RDS security group not working

Tags: amazon-rds, amazon-iam

Our project is currently hosted on AWS. We are using RDS service for data tier. I need to give permission to one of my IAM user to handle IP address addition/removal request for the security group associated with my RDS instance. Tried making custom policy for this case. Below is my JSON for policy -

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "rds:AuthorizeDBSecurityGroupIngress",
            "rds:ListTagsForResource",
            "rds:DownloadDBLogFilePortion",
            "rds:RevokeDBSecurityGroupIngress"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:rds:ap-south-1:608862704225:secgrp:<security-group name>",
            "arn:aws:rds:ap-south-1:608862704225:db:<db name>"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "rds:DescribeDBClusterSnapshots",
            "rds:DownloadCompleteDBLogFile"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    }
]
```

This isn't working despite various changes. Can anybody suggest where am I going wrong ? Any solution too would be welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer myself, actually was trying to make that work through permissions in RDS instance directly. Instead, security group permissions needs to be handled in ec2 policies.